# What Is the Intuition of Convolution in The Signal Processing World

Tags: convolution, linear-systems, math

It is known that an LTI system is defined by its Impulse Response and the Convolution Operator.

Could some put some intuition behind?

Thank You.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution

Comment: It seems like homework

Comment: I edited the question in a manner that both reflect the OP and is relevant to the forum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this MathOverflow post gives a lot of intuition about Convolution: [What's convolution intuitively](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/5892/)?

In the Signal Processing world, an LTI (Linear and Time Invariant) system basically scales and sums delayed versions of the input signal.

This can be mathematically described using the integral known as convolution.